# Fetch ApexChart data from API using axios in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, apexcharts

Using ApexChart I manage to display the data from a local const, but I can't display this data fetching with axios.

I can't get data result, console.log or error

**File that manage the chart option**

```
export const chartData = {
    height: 460,
    type: 'rangeBar',
    id: 'range-chart',
    options: {
        chart: {
    ... },
    series: []
};
```

**File that display the chart**

```
const MainChart = ({ isLoading }) => {

    const [rawdata, setRawdata] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadData = async () => {
            const res = await axiosConfig.get(`/<ENDPOINT>/`)
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('data load', res.data.record) //is showing nothing
                    setRawata([{
                        data: res.data.record
                    }])
                }
                )
        }
    }, [])
 return (
        <>
            {isLoading ? (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            ) : (
                <Grid container spacing={0}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} mt={5}>
                        <Chart
                        options={{
                            ...chartData.options
                          }} 
                            series={[{
                                data: rawdata
                              }]}
                             />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            )}
        </>
    );
```

I only get options. I don't have any data result, no console log and no console error

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question in case help to others.

After investigating I solved my own question.

In React ApexChart you can pass all the values from one file, or split options from other values.

In the file that manage the options

```
export const chartData = {
    // height: 460,
    // type: 'rangeBar',
    // id: 'range-chart',
    options: {
        chart: {
    ... },
    series: []
};
```

Chart component. Here you pass options, series and the 3 values that you commented on the options files.

```
<Chart
                            id="range-chart"
                            type="rangeBar"
                            height={460}
                            options={{
                                ...chartData.options
                            }}
                            series={
                                data
                            }
                        />
```

The fetch issue is not related with ApexChart, but as you can guess there was a bad syntax.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData()
    }, [])

    const loadData = async () => {
        const res = await axiosConfig.get(`<ENDPOINT>`)
        setData(res.data.record)
    }
```